# hiding login option from react native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've set up my react native project with all the usual authentication options. Then I've set up a drawer navigation and can successfully navigate between all the authentication screens and the main screens.

It makes no sense to have a `Login` option taking up space on the menu when the user is already logged in, so I tried to hide it based on login status using a Context. The context works perfectly, but I now get an error after logging in when I try to navigate back to the previous page.  `ERROR  The action 'GO_BACK' was not handled by any navigator. Is there any screen to go back to?`

This is a development only error that won't appear in production, but I assume there's a way to do this that doesn't cause errors and will return to the previous screen rather than to the initial screen.

Here's my code in case it's something I'm actually doing wrong.
NavMenu.js

```js
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
    import IndexBooks from './books/IndexBooks';
    import IndexSeries from './series/IndexSeries';
    import LoginScreen from './auth/LoginScreen';
    import LogoutScreen from './auth/LogoutScreen';
    import RegisterScreen from './auth/RegisterScreen';
    import ResetPasswordScreen from './auth/ResetPasswordScreen';
    import { AuthContext } from './auth/AuthCentext';
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
    export default function NavMenu() {
        const { user } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    
        return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator 
                initialRouteName='Home'
            >
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="Home" 
                    component={HomeScreen} 
                />
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="Books" 
                    component={IndexBooks} 
                    options={{ title: 'Books' }}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen 
                    name="Series" 
                    component={IndexSeries} 
                    options={{ title: 'Reading Lists' }} 
                />
                {/* {user == null && */}
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Login"
                        component={LoginScreen}
                    />
                {/* } */}
                {user == null &&
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Register"
                        component={RegisterScreen}
                    />
                }
                {user !== null &&
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Logout"
                        component={LogoutScreen}
                    />
                }
                {user !== null &&
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Reset Password"
                        component={ResetPasswordScreen}
                    />
                }
                </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
```

LoginScreen.js

```js
    // send the login request
    const handleLogin = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('/api/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password,
                device_name: 'mobile',
            });
    
            // on success add the token to axios defaults for future requests
            const csrfToken = response.data.token;
            const user = response.data.user.id.toString();
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${csrfToken}`;
    
            // then save it for use in future app sessions and return to previous screen
            try {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('user', user);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('csrfToken', csrfToken);
                setUser(user);
                navigation.goBack();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('error', e);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            Alert.alert('Login Failed', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');
        }
    };
```

How can this be done without generating an error?

Comment: I'm finding more problems with using the Drawer, like navigating to screens that have no value without props provided in context of other screens. They don't belong in the drawer, but I still want them on the stack. I'm thinking that I need to use Stack rather than Drawer and create my own drawer that I have full control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in [this example,](https://snack.expo.dev/@therketan/drawertabstack) which led me to the documentation I missed for the [Drawer Navigator.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawercontent) The drawer navigator component allows you to completely overwrite the drawer content and add your own by using the attribute `drawerContent`.

```js
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    
    export default function NavMenu() {
        const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    
        return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator 
                initialRouteName='Home'
                drawerContent={(props) => (
                    <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />
                )}
            >
                    <Drawer.Screen 
                        name="Home" 
                        component={HomeScreen} 
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Login"
                        component={LoginScreen}
                    />
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name="Logout"
                        component={LogoutScreen}
                    />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
```

The custom content doesn't have access to `navigation` by default, but you can give it access with [`useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/).

```js
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

    const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
        const navigation = useNavigation();
        const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
        console.log('user', user);
    
        return (
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <DrawerItem
                    label="Home"
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
                />
                {user === null &&
                    <DrawerItem 
                        label="Log In"
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
                    />
                }
                {user !== null &&
                    <DrawerItem 
                        label="Log Out"
                        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Logout')}
                    />
                }
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        );
    }
```

Comment: After further testing, this solution doesn't work particularly well. 'goBack' will only ever open the 'initialRoutenName' screen (whether it's included in the custom drawer content or not).

Comment: And this last was solved using `<Drawer.Navigator backBehaviour='history'>`